# step, lines, tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hei,
Can somebody help me with making those lines from the picture?
[image]

Comment: Search for `patterns` in the TikZ manual or on this site with [tag:tikz-pgf]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

for more complete image you should show us, what you try so far ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.append style = {%
        font=\footnotesize, anchor=south, sloped}                            
                        ]
\draw[thick,
      pattern=north east lines
      ]
      (0,0) to ["\SI{30}{cm}"] ++ (0,6)
            -- ++ (3,-3)
            -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.
Everything else I have done.

Comment: @Johy, if answer solve your problem, than you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)